# How does djangoproject.com do its deploy to prod? Should I package my django project to deploy it?

Tags: python, django, deployment, packaging

I know this isn't exactly a SO-style question, but I think it would be very instructive to know the answer.

The [source](https://github.com/django/djangoproject.com) for **djangoproject.com** is very helpful for understanding a possible layout for a Django project. However, the lack of a `setup.py` file suggests that this project is not "packaged" to put it into production.

I am not interested in any of "how to setup nginx", "which DB to use", "how to `<insert detail of hosting>`". What I am interested in knowing includes:

1. How do they deploy the `djangoproject.com` part to their production servers?

   - Do they just do a `git pull` on their box to get the files in place? Or an scp/rsync/ftp?
   - Who/what executes this step? I'm guessing it is automated, but does it trigger based on tags? or off .tar.gz files placed in a special location? (Given there are no tags/releases and only one `master` branch in the github project I'm guessing that whatever makes it onto `master` gets deployed?)
2. How to they manage rolling back if they need to? / Is it automated?(the actual details are not necessary, but the general info would be good)
3. Should I package my applications for deployment or not?

   - I have always preferred a packaged deployment (i.e. I package my project, put it in a private PyPI and have a separate "deploy" project that installs from that), but I'm starting to doubt whether it is necessary / a good idea or not.

There are lots of questions on here about the details of deployment in various situations (apache vs nginx, AWS vs heroku vs your own, ansible vs fabric vs...), but I'm really trying to focus on the nexus of packaging / project layout and deploying.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open-ended question.

1. I would definitely advise against `git pull` for many reasons.. i.e, pulling unwanted code into a production environment. There are many CI/CD services, ie AWS codedeploy, to automate this process.
2. Rollback can also be automated at CI/CD level, many services allow you to pick a deployed revision to roll back, and/or redeploy a new revision from a previous git commit.
3. I have not seen this type of deployment just yet.. You have the right idea, I would recommend you to check out [Docker and Docker Compose](https://www.docker.com/)